# How do I configure this php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array:

```
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone@example.com";
```

How would I configure this array to contain more than one email address?

I am having a hard time figuring out what this method of creating a php array is doing.

Comment: You don't configure an array. Just add an element if you need to

Comment: By invoking the line of code you've provided multiple times with different emails you add them to $msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'] array

Comment: What you really need is to make research efforts, like reading PHP manual about what is an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) inside PHP context and about [`array_`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:
1.

```
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array(
  'someone1@example.com',
  'someone2@example.com',
  // some other emails
);
```

2.

```
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone1@example.com";
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone2@example.com";
```

This "[]" notation means "append a new value to an array".
If `$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses']` subarray doesn't exist before an execution of the first append operator then it will be created, hence you can start using this operator right away without having to create an empty array in advance.

Answer (score 6):

If you have already set `$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses']` to be an array by using `$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array();` then you can simply add as many email addresses as you want the same way you added the first:

```
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone@example.com";
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone2@example.com";
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone3@example.com";
```

You could also add all of them at one time:

```
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array(
    "someone@example.com",
    "someone2@example.com",
    "someone3@example.com"
);
```

Comment: I was just typing very similar answer. To extend that, such array would have numeric index so emails can be accessed like `$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][0]` which will retrieve `"someone@example.com"`.

Comment: You actually do not need to have previously defined the array to use the first approach. The first assignment to `$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][]` will create it with no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Keep assigning the value to this array. This is basically the third dimension of the array.

```
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone1@example.com";
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone2@example.com";
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone3@example.com";
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "someone4@example.com";
```

The first value of array is first email, then second one and so on, if you want to assign an array to that first value you can do like

```
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = array("someone1@example.com","email2@email2.com");
```

or may be just an array to `ToAddresses` like this :

```
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses']= array("someone1@example.com","email2@email2.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the array_push() function in php which insert one or multiple value to the end of an array will solve your question. Find the code below

```
   <?php
        $msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array("oyedele@yahoo.com","idow@gmail.com");

        $new =array_push($msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'], "itz4mesays@google.net","zya3@demo.com","itz4mesays@google.net");

        var_dump($msg['Destination']['ToAddresses']);
    ?>
```

You can add as many as possible to the array_push values.

I hope it solves your question.